# Image of the unit square under linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

> Let $\mathbf{B} = \begin{pmatrix}1&-1 \\ 3 & -2\end{pmatrix}.$ The
>   image of the unit square in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under the linear mapping
>   $T_{\mathbf{B}}: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by
>   $T_\mathbf{B}{\mathbf{x}} = \mathbf{Bx}$ is
>
> (A) a square; (B) a non-square rectangle; (C) a non-rectangular
>   parallelogram; (D) a line segment; (E) the point $(1, −2)$; (F) none of
>   these.

I think it takes $(0,0) \mapsto (0,0)$, $(1,0) \mapsto (1,3)$, $(0,1) \mapsto (-1,-2)$, and $(1,1) \mapsto (0,1)$. Is this right? I can't figure out what shape it should be.

Comment: The resulting (image) points look correct. If it is a parallelogram (or rectangle), the opposite sides need to be of the same length and same slope. You could check that.

Comment: @OKPALAMMADUABUCHI How can a “unit” square have an area of $4$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an image of the unit square image:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

If it’s a rectangle adjacent sides will be perpendicular. Take the dot product of adjacent sides. If $0$ it’s a rectangle or a square. If not $0$ it’s a parallelogram. Btw if two adjacent sides point in the same direction it’s a line. If the determinant is zero it’s a point. No matrix is a translation so if determinant is zero, it’s the point $(0,0)$.

Comment: We're given that $T_B$ sends $x\mapsto Bx$ for some $2\times2$ matrix $B$. The image of the unit square will be a point iff $B=0$. $\det(B)=0$ iff the image of the unit square is either a line segment or a point.

Comment: If you fix the mistakes in this post, then this will be a good post.